# Replace keywords in an array of strings with previous elements up to a specific one

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, loops, ecmascript-6

I have an array of strings with the following elements:

```
2+2
3+3

sum

# Example comment
5+5

3+2

sum

# Random word
10-5
sum
```

I would like to replace each word `sum` with elements before it separated with `+`, but up to a recent comment (ex. `# Example comment`). So for the array above the output should be:

```
2+2
3+3

2+2+3+3

# Example comment
5+5

3+2

5+5+3+2

# Random word
10-5
10-5
```

Notice that the first "block" doesn't have a comment as it is at the beginning of the array, but it still works correctly. What's the best way to achieve such a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with one `for-loop` while using an array to save the items until a comment is reached (this case we would empty it and continue):

```js
const arr = [
  "2+2",
  "3+3",

  "sum",

  "# Example comment",

  "5+5",
  "3+2",

  "sum",

  "# Random word",

  "10-5",
  
  "sum"
];

let items = [];

for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  const item = arr[i];
  if(item === "sum") arr[i] = items.join("+");
  else if(item.startsWith("#")) items = [];
  else items.push(item);
}

console.log(arr);
```